# Loss is decreasing and accuracy is not improving in siamese network with contrastive loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# We have 2 inputs, 1 for each picture
left_input = Input(img_size)
right_input = Input(img_size)

# We will use 2 instances of 1 network for this task
convnet = Sequential([
 Conv2D(4,3, input_shape=img_size, padding='same'),
 Activation('relu'),
 MaxPooling2D(),
 Conv2D(4,3, padding='same'),
 Activation('relu'),
 MaxPooling2D(),
 Conv2D(4,3, padding='same'),
 Activation('relu'),
 MaxPooling2D(),
 Conv2D(4,3, padding='same'),
 Activation('relu'),
 Flatten(),
 Dropout(0.3),
 Dense(18),
 Activation('sigmoid')
])
# Connect each 'leg' of the network to each input
# Remember, they have the same weights
encoded_l = convnet(left_input)
encoded_r = convnet(right_input)

# Getting the L1 Distance between the 2 encodings
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensor:K.abs(tensor[0] - tensor[1]))

# Add the distance function to the network
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)

optimizer = Adam(lr, decay=2.5e-4)

#//TODO: get layerwise learning rates and momentum annealing scheme described in paperworking
siamese_net.compile(loss=tfa.losses.contrastive.contrastive_loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['acc'])

siamese_net.summary()
```

my accuracy is decreasing eventhough loss value is decreasing?
I have got output like this

```
Epoch 1/10 6368/6368 [==============================] - 647s 102ms/step - loss: 0.1762 - acc: 0.2134 - val_loss: 0.1590 - val_acc: 0.1784 
Epoch 2/10 6368/6368 [==============================] - 1094s 172ms/step - loss: 0.1649 - acc: 0.1881 - val_loss: 0.1548 - val_acc: 0.1784 
Epoch 3/10 6368/6368 [==============================] - 1440s 226ms/step - loss: 0.1573 - acc: 0.1779 - val_loss: 0.1515 - val_acc: 0.1790
```

may i know what is the reason why my accuracy is reducing even though the loss function is reducing?

Comment: def acc(y_true, y_pred):
    ones = K.ones_like(y_pred)
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, ones - K.clip(K.round(y_pred), 0, 1)), axis=-1)
i have used this accuracy function instead of keras inbuild accuracy function

Comment: your second epoch is not even complete, can you wait for it to complete and then get back if you observe the same thing.

Comment: Actually i have tried another model with less number of parameters. I have got the same error.

Comment: I would request the same thing again, wait for 3-4 epochs to complete and post the complete log of training, then it makes sense to comment on if the loss is actually going up or down, It is hard to make suggestions based on the middle of a training epoch.

Comment: Train on 6368 samples, validate on 1592 samples
````
Epoch 1/10
6368/6368 [==============================] - 647s 102ms/step - loss: 0.1762 - acc: 0.2134 - val_loss: 0.1590 - val_acc: 0.1784
Epoch 2/10
6368/6368 [==============================] - 1094s 172ms/step - loss: 0.1649 - acc: 0.1881 - val_loss: 0.1548 - val_acc: 0.1784
Epoch 3/10
6368/6368 [==============================] - 1440s 226ms/step - loss: 0.1573 - acc: 0.1779 - val_loss: 0.1515 - val_acc: 0.1790 ````

This is the result after 3 Epochs.

Comment: since your output is just 1 value and not an embedding i think you should change your loss to `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: I have already tried with Binary_Cross-entropy. that did not workout with my dataset. That is why i am trying the model with contrastive loss